# BigQuery Command Line - How to use parameters in the query string?

Tags: linux, bash, google-bigquery, gcloud

I am writing a shell script which involves BigQuery commands to query an existing table and save the results to a destination table.

However, since my script will be run periodically, I have a parameter for the date for which the query should run.

For example, my script looks like this:

```
DATE_FORMATTED=$(date +%Y%m%d)

bq query --destination_table=Desttables.abc_$DATE_FORMATTED "select hits_eventInfo_eventLabel from TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.table_],TIMESTAMP($DATE_FORMATTED),TIMESTAMP($DATE_FORMATTED)) where customDimensions_index = 4"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'pro-cn:bqjob_r5437894379_1': FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table
```

How else can I pass the variable `$DATE_FORMATTED` to the `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` function from BigQuery in order to help execute my query?

Comment: The parameter expansion here looks right (if your timestamp really is things like 20151112 rather than an actual POSIX timestamp). Are you sure the error is due to the parameter expansion? Doesn't look that way to me. The problem seems to be what's said in the error message: "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table".

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes `""` + single quote `''`. For example, in your case:

```
TIMESTAMP("'$DATE_FORMATTED'")
```

OR

```
select "'$variable'" as dummy from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the single quotes around the `$DATE_FORMATTED` value inside the `TIMESTAMP` functions. Without the quotes it's going to be defaulting to the EPOCH time.

Try with:

```
TIMESTAMP('$DATE_FORMATTED'),TIMESTAMP('$DATE_FORMATTED')
```

Comment: I tried with single quotes as well - got the same error.

Comment: also add the dashes to your string DATE_FORMATTED=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)